# Jquery : After completion of 'fade in' effect, wait for 'click' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I wait for a click event ?
eg. I want that my `<div>` wait for 3 seconds after it's fade in, and if within 3 seconds the `<div>` is not clicked then it fade out.

I tried to give time 2 seconds in fadeOut but mouse click is not working it just fadeOut.

my .js file code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".arrow").hide()

$(".container").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".arrow").fadeIn()
});

$(".container").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".arrow").fadeOut(2000)
});

$(".arrow").click(function () {
    $(".container").hide()
});
```

Comment: ok @Eshwer here is code ^

Comment: Please post your HTML markup too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = 0;

    $(".container").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".arrow").fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(clicked == 0) {
                $(".arrow").fadeOut(2000);
            }
        },3000);
    });

    $(".container").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".arrow").fadeOut(2000);
    });

    $(".container").click(function () {
        clicked = 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but your onClick handler isn't working because syntax is wrong.

Try this:

```
$(".arrow").on('click', function () {
    $(".container").hide()
});
```

Also you seem to be missing the closing braces of the `ready`-function.

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 // Your code here

}); // Don't forget this line
```

Comment: it was typing mistake it is '.click' in actual code not '.Onclick'

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to check if arrow has been clicked at the end of your time limit.

## Example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = false;

    $(".arrow").click(function () {
        clicked = true;
    });

    $(".container").hover(function () { // i put the two mouseenter, mouseleave functions into one hover(mousein, mouseout) function
        $(".arrow").fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (clicked === false) {
                $(".arrow").fadeOut(2000);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }, function () {
        $(".arrow").fadeOut(2000);
        clicked = false; // i don't know if you want this or not. this resets everything on mouseout. if you want the .arrow thing to stay even after the mouse leaves .container, just get rid of this line
    }); // .hover
}); // .ready
```